# Git apply a change to all files in all previous commits

Tags: git, sed, git-rewrite-history

I would like to apply a change to all my files in my git history. More precisely, I would like to modify a specific line which is the author name (it is written in the header of all my files, I am not talking about the git author) to remove the previous value from all the git history and change it by the new one.
So far, I have tried to use `git filter-branch` to perform the following command:
`sed -i -e "s/<previous_author>/<new_author>/"` which works perfectly when I try it on a single file (<previous_author> is indeed replaced by <new_author> in the file).
However, when I use `git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'sed -i -e "s/<previous_author>/<new_author>/"' HEAD` I get an error `sed: -i may not be used with stdin`. I tried to do something similar with `git rebase` but I get the same error.
So is there a way to do this, so to exec `sed -i -e "s/<previous_author>/<new_author>/"` on all files of all my previous commits ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write a filter that actually acts on every file. Your sed command is OK, it just needs a wrapper along the lines of "find each file one at a time, run sed on the found file, report success". Some versions of sed can take multiple file arguments - if you have one of those consider using `find` and `xargs` to cut down the number of `sed` invocations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

```sh
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter \
'if git grep --name-only "@author";  
 then
    git grep --name-only "@author" | xargs sed -i -e "s/@prev_auth/@new_author/"
 fi'
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well ! However after using this I get a duplicate of all my files with -e in their names (for example myFile.txt gets modified but I get a new file myFile.txt-e which is a copy of the initial one), do you have any idea on how to remove them / how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I'm glad this helped :) can you share your command you use. This sounds strange as an output

Comment: I used exactly your command :
`git filter-branch -f --tree-filter \
'if git grep --name-only "@prev_auth";  
 then
    git grep --name-only "@prev_auth" | xargs sed -i -e "s/@prev_auth/@new_author/"
 fi'`.
I precise that those files are present in all commits in my git history.

Comment: Are these files with the appended `-e` at the end tracked by git? If not, you can just delete them.

Comment: I have no idea why this happens to you. I cannot reproduce this behavior on my box. But if they are not tracked, then you can delete them with the following command. `find . -name '*-e' -delete`. First run it without `delete` and make sure that it outputs the desired files, then run with delete.

Comment: @Seth: The `-e` file is occurring because your particular `sed` interprets `-i -e` as: *make a backup file by adding `-e` to the file's name*. Different `sed` commands treat `-i` arguments differently; yours requires `-i ''`.